# Creating a hidden file in Common Lisp

Tags: windows, common-lisp, hidden-files, allegro-cl

Since hidden files on a Unix platform simply start with a period, it is trivial to create one using Common Lisp. Hidden files on Windows machines are defined differently. They have a [file attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute) that indicates whether they are hidden. How can one create these type of files using Common Lisp? I'm using Allegro CL on Windows.

Comment: In pure Common Lisp, you probably can't.  Allegro might give you a way to, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI CL standard offers no such functionality.
Your vendor might provide it though.

How about [`file-hidden-p`](http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/operators/excl/file-hidden-p.htm):

```
(setf (file-hidden-p "my-file") t)
```

PS. Note that I have not used Allegro for over 15 years. The information above is from Google:

1. search for [allegro lisp file attribute](https://www.google.com/search?q=allegro+lisp+file+attribute)
2. [first hit](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/iacl.htm)
3. click on [PermutedIndex](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/permuted-index.htm)
4. click on [A](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/permuted-index-a.htm) and find [`file-attributes`](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/permuted-index-a.htm)
5. read the doc and see [`file-hidden-p`](http://franz.com/support/documentation/9.0/doc/operators/excl/file-hidden-p.htm)

Still, as I said before - do not hesitate to ask ;-)